# split text with specific word + text come to new line

Tags: excel, vba

First, I also want to split text according to specific word. Then, I want to split the text one by one automatically.

1 ID001 Company Name: ABC Limited Address: Central ID002 Company Name: Delino Company Address: Mong Kok ID003 Company Name: Moria Company Address: Shatin ID004 Company Name: Sherlyn Company Address: Mong Kok ID005 Company Name: Coco Company Address: Shatin

2 ID010 Company Name: Toro Limited Address: Central ID012 Company Name: Benz Company Address: Mong Kok ID013 Company Name: Korz Company Address: Shatin ID014 Company Name: Chopra Company Address: Mong Kok ID015 Company Name: Toto Company Address: Shatin

I tried to use vba.

```
Dim rng As Range

Dim FullName As Varient 

With ActiveSheet

    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 1))

    FullName = split(rng,"ID")

End With
```

Before: 
 [image]

After: 
 [image]

Comment: So what problems are you facing?

Comment: The vba doesn't work. Maybe the code is not correct.

Comment: If the text is in one line, you can use `Data|TextToColumns|Fixed Width` You do not need VBA for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this...

Remember to change the Data sheet before testing the code if it is not Sheet1.

```
Sub SplitText()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim FullName() As String
Dim lr As Long, i As Long, dlr As Long
Dim str()

Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")   'Sheet with Data
lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = wsData.Range("A1:A" & lr)

Set dws = Worksheets.Add

For Each cel In rng
    FullName = Split(cel.Value, "ID")
    ReDim str(1 To UBound(FullName), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(FullName)
        str(i, 1) = "ID" & Left(FullName(i), InStr(FullName(i), " ") - 1)
        str(i, 2) = VBA.Trim(Right(FullName(i), Len(FullName(i)) - 3))
    Next i

    If dws.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        dlr = 1
    Else
        dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    dws.Range("A" & dlr).Resize(UBound(str, 1), 2).Value = str
    Erase str
Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to do this. The following will match all values in your range between two "ID" blocks or between an "ID" and the end of the line

```
Public Sub RegExDemo()
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim submatches, match, matches
    Dim RowIndex As Long, j As Long
    Dim c

    With Sheet2
        arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1)).Value2
    End With

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(ID[0-9]{1,}) (.*?)(?= ID[0-9]{1,}|$)"

        RowIndex = 1

        For Each c In arr
            If .test(c) Then
                Set matches = .Execute(c)
                For Each match In matches
                    Set submatches = match.submatches
                    For j = 0 To submatches.Count - 1
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Offset(0, j).Value2 = Trim(submatches(j))
                    Next j
                    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
                Next match
            End If
        Next c
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .Rows.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Producing:

[image]